# Piano pitch detection

Tags: pitch, piano

I read a lot of articles and discussions about FFT and algorithms about pitch detection (autocorrelation, overlapping windows, HPS...). When we play the piano so there are not only one frequency but many - high and low frequencies, so what is the best method for piano?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about DSP theory (polyphonic pitch detection) and so belongs on http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about what you are trying to do, but it seems to me you need to run some high pass and low pass filters, isolate your data set so you can get the pitch from the noise. Piano has many frequencies to give you the tonal characteristics of its sound, but if you only care about pitch, (the exact note being hit) then the rest of the waveform is noise to you. Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to get the notes that person plays. For example if person press keys: c4, d4, e4 in the same time, I want find out it.

Comment: ok. well there are MANY ways to do this. Hard coding this will be very complex depending on your skill level. have you looked into back propogating neural networks? I have used them for similar problems in the past, they do all the heavy lifting for you. if you find it not suitable, i can explain the hard code procedure for you. i suggest you look at these: http://www.seattlerobotics.org/encoder/nov98/neural.html

Comment: Thanks for code procedure, but what about some concrete method, technique... of pitch detection suitable for piano?

Comment: if you use the BPNN, the code would work for ANY instrument. the NN would learn new instruments easily. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/neurolab

Comment: feed it your data set, tell it what chord/note is actually being played. do this for all notes/chords. let the code run and run, and presto, you have your solution. it will learn itself how to figure out the chord and you dont have to worry about the details.

Comment: it won´t be work, because there are a lot of combination how can be keys press together.

Comment: thats exactly why this will work. its perfectly suited to it. if you supply thosecombinations to its learning, it wont have an issue. writing code to iteration through the combinations is trivial as well. if ou are still stuck, hit me in chat pls as this thread is getting too long.

Comment: I don´t look trivial solution for coding. This is trival, very easy solution but it will take long time, if I find right combination. For example for all 10 fingers are 4.513667845896 × 10^12 combinations and remain 9, 8 etc...It is bad solution from the perspective of a programmer and real time.